# Rengine.GetInstance() shows error

Tags: c#, .net, r, rest, r.net

While connecting R from windows application on VS2015 framework 4.6, Its working fine. But when the same code i have added to **webservice** it throws an exception

> System.NullReferenceException' occurred in RDotNet.dll but was not handled in user code

at the line

```
REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have two or more RDotNet.dll's on your computer a newer and a older version. This can happen when you install a new program and then uninstall the older program after installing the newer software that use the same dll. Your project maybe pointing to the older version but since you have a newer version of RDotNet.dll it works on your computer since the pointer then will point to the newer dll. This will however not work on the webservice. To fix this you have to uninstall all the software that uses the RDotNet.dll's. Install it again and change the pointer to the newer dll.